# Has Google just changed their historical stock price interface (again)?

Tags: http, google-finance-api

For years I've been using web page requests like the following to retrieve 20 days at a time of minutewise stock data from Google:

http://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=.INX&i=60&p=20d&f=d,c,h,l,o,v

= Retrieve for .INX (S&P 500 index) 60-second interval data for the last 20 days, with format Datetime(in Unix format), Close, High, Low, Open, Volume.

The Datetime is in Unix format (seconds since 1/1/1970, prefixed with an "A") for the first entry of each day, and subsequent entries show the intervals that have passed (so 1 = 60 seconds after the opening of the market that day).

That worked up until 9/10/2017, but today (9/17) it only returns day-end data (it even reports the "interval" between samples as 86400). Pooey! I can get that anywhere, in bulk.

But if I ask for fewer days, or broader intervals, it seems to return data - but weird data. Asking for data every 120 seconds returns exactly that - but only for every other market day. Weird!

Has anyone got a clue what might have happened?

Answer (score 0):

Whoa! I think I figured it out.

Google still returns minutewise data for the same approximate limitations (up to 20 calendar days), but instead of d=10 returning all the market data for the last 10 *calendar* days, it return the data for the last 10 *market* days. Previously, to get the last 10 market days you would ask for d=14 (M-Fx2, plus two weekends). Now, Google interprets the d variable as market days, and asking for d=20 exceeds the limits on what they will deliver.

It now appears that d=15 is the limit (three weeks of market days). No clue on why I got the very weird every-other-day data for a while... but maybe if you exceed their d-limits the intervals get screwy. Dunno. Don't care. Easy fix.